# What does function[(thisArg)]) syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm going through [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) and got a bit confused of what they trying to say here `React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])` when they wrap function argument into square and round brackets simultaneously `function[(thisArg)]`. Can anyone explain the meaning please?

Comment: Related: [How to interpret API documentation function parameters?](/q/10925478/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [*meant*](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4339) to mean that `.map` accepts an optional third argument, which is the `thisArg` to invoke the passed function with. But the syntax given in the documentation is very confusing. Put in a more standard way, it would be:

```
React.Children.map(children, functionToInvoke[, thisArg])
```

or

```
React.Children.map(children, function(child, index)[, thisArg])
```

which is how [MDN does it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax), putting the optional argument(s) in square brackets *after* the required arguments are stated.